# PowerBuilder application got "SQL Error 16945 The cursor was not declared"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, powerbuilder

I have script using cursor embedded in Powerbuilder 6 source code, it's connecting to SQL Server 2008 R2 as below.

```
DECLARE cdept CURSOR FOR
SELECT de0070 AS dept_code,
        de0080 AS dept_name,
        (CASE WHEN de0010 = 'A' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END) AS active_status,
        de0120 AS div_code
FROM APFLIB.JPMDEPP  
WHERE de0010 = 'A'
ORDER BY de0070
USING l_trans;
```

but when I run the application I got "SQL Error 16945 The cursor was not declared." after I checked with this script:

```
MessageBox("SQL error " + String(l_trans.SQLDBCode), l_trans.SQLErrText)
```

[SQL Error 16945](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPuZ5.png)
I've tried to change CLR Integration in SQL server properties but still no luck. How can I fix this error?

Comment: and what is USING l_trans; in the cursor declaration

Comment: @Sergey it's the syntax for Powerbuilder when using the database transactions 

declared as

l_trans = CREATE Transaction

The error in the picture is from this code

MessageBox("SQL error " + String(l_trans.SQLDBCode), l_trans.SQLErrText)

Comment: @MitchWheat I'm using administrator running the application and connecting the database with sa but still got this error :(

Comment: `USING ...` is not part of T-SQL as far as I can tell.

Comment: @TT. it's actually part of Powerbuilder script when using database transasction.

Comment: Why do you want to use a `CURSOR` in the first place? SQL is a set based language, and a `CURSOR` is iterative. What are you *really* trying to achieve here?

Comment: Are you checking sqlcode=0 first to **know** there is an error? And to everyone else - this is Powerbuilder specific syntax and not straight Tsql. The "using" part is specific to Powerbuilder and acts as the connection to the database

Comment: @Larnu the retrieved rows will be processed in the while loop after that.

Comment: @SMor yes, actually I got a statemet to check the sqlcode first

IF l_trans.SQLCode <> 0 THEN
 MessageBox("SQL error " + String(l_trans.SQLDBCode), l_trans.SQLErrText)
END IF

Comment: *"the retrieved rows will be processed in the while loop after that. "* and again why do you *want* to do that. Again SQL is a SET BASED language...

Comment: @Larnu actually this is the code of the past programmer, but as I can tell, she wants to pass the cursor to PowerBuilder part, PB function will fetch the result from cursor and process row by row.

Comment: So why not fix the SQL and not use a `CURSOR`..?

Comment: @Larnu This is application code, not tsql code. Stop assuming. And AFAIK this does in fact create an actual client-side cursor. There are many reasons for RBAR processing in a application - this could be a queue of sorts requiring a series of complicated actions for each row.

Comment: Jeepers - I just saw "Powerbuilder 6". No offense but that is so old and obsolete that you won't get much help. Perhaps it is a driver issue - I imagine that it is using the old dblib-based driver still. Are you running this as an executable or via the IDE? Not that I can really offer anything useful since that IDE is almost 25 years old. If you're trying to modify that code, I think you may have hurdles much too high to overcome.

Comment: *"This is application code, not tsql code. Stop assuming."* When the OP isn't explicit we have no choice other than to, @SMor .

Comment: So you listed the DECLARE CURSOR statement from within PowerScript but when do you get the error?  Are you using the OPEN  statement when it occurs?